# how to distribute a vector between workers in a spmd block

Tags: matlab, spmd

I have a spmd block inside a for-loop. I need a 2*9 vector called Aa to be distributed between three or more workers, some calculations are performed and as a result, few matrices and vectors are generated. then the matrices of each worker and all workers are concatenated together. The resulted matrix and vector are converted to double and a new spmd block is started. The error "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch" is shown when I run the code. Can I increase the number of workers? 
Here is some part of the code:

Thank you in advance

```
   Aa=[0 0; 0 1; 0 2; 1 0; 1 1; 1 2; 2 0; 2 1; 2 2 ];

   for n=3:TGponts1

 % &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
 %        In this part, some calculation is done on Good_path_1 and R2_1
 %        and a new Good_path1_1 and R_1 and s1_1 are defined

 % &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

q_1=0; q_2=0;
nn1=n-1; nn2=2*n-2;

spmd (3)
    for ss=1:3  %   To assign three pairs of Aa to any worker
        if (ss == 1)
            a=Aa(labindex,1);
            b=Aa(labindex,2);
        elseif (ss == 2)
            a=Aa(labindex+3,1);
            b=Aa(labindex+3,2);
        else
            a=Aa(labindex+6,1);
            b=Aa(labindex+6,2);
        end
        Sum1=single(0);

        %             Here, some calculation is done.

        if p>thr_Wght
            q_1=q_1+1;

            if n<=n_c1

                Good_path1_1(q_1,1:2*n)=
             [a,Good_path_1(k_1,1:nn1),b,Good_path_1(k_1,n:nn2)];
            else
                Good_path1_1(q_1,1:L)=
             [a,Good_path_1(k_1,1:n_c),b,Good_path_1(k_1,n_c1:n_c2)];
            end

            R_1(q_1)=R3;

            Sum1=Sum1+R3;
        end

        %             Each worker performs these commands three times.
        Good_path1_1(q_1+1:s1_1,:)=[];
        R_1(1,q_1+1:s1_1)=[];
        %             Is it true to write like this to avoid that the third 
        %             (second) Good_path1_1 and R_1 are not replaced with 
                       the second (first) one?
        Good_path1_1ew(:,:,ss)=Good_path1_1;
        R_1ew(:,ss)= R_1;
        % &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&
    end
end

% Here all the Good_path1_1 of each worker and all workers are concatenated
Good_path1_1 = gcat(Good_path1_1ew, 1);
R_1=gcat(R_1ew, 1);
% &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&

Good_path1_1=str2double(Good_path1_1);
R_1=str2double(R_1);

% Here Good_path1_1 and R_1 are substituted into Good_path_1 and R2_1
Good_path_1=Good_path1_1;
R2_1=R_1;    
end
```

Comment: It would be great if you could come up with a "minimal complete verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - it's not really clear from the above what's going wrong.

Comment: In a very short statement, the main question is how I can distribute a 2*9 vector between three workers of spmd block as each of the workers use three of them for three times (one time for each of three pairs) to perform calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works well for that purpose.

```
    Aa=[0 0; 0 1; 0 2; 1 0; 1 1; 1 2; 2 0; 2 1; 2 2 ]; 
    spmd (3)
        for ss=1:3  %   To assign three pairs of Aa to any worker

            if (labindex==1)
                a=Aa(ss,1);
                b=Aa(ss,2);
            elseif (labindex==2)
                a=Aa(3+ss,1);
                b=Aa(3+ss,2);
            else
                a=Aa(6+ss,1);
                b=Aa(6+ss,2);
            end
           % the remaining commands with some modifications

    end
```